# Any other ways to get query results in firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

Right now I get query results like that:

```
Query query = db.collection("Videos").whereEqualTo("publisherId", model.getUserId());

query.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        if (task.getResult() != null) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                Video video = documentSnapshot.toObject(Video.class);

                thumbUrl = video.getThumbUrl();
                videoTitle = video.getVideoTitle();
                videoUrl = video.getVideoUrl();
                videoDesc = video.getVideoDesc();
                videoId = video.getVideoId();
                publisherId = video.getPublisherId();
            }

            if (task.getResult().size() != 0) {
                Glide.with(context).load(model.getUserImageUrl()).into(holder.userProfileImage);
                Glide.with(context).load(thumbUrl).into(holder.videoImageView);
                holder.videoTitle.setText(videoTitle);
                holder.mainContainerVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (task.getResult().size() == 0) {
                holder.mainContainerVideo.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
                holder.mainContainerVideo.getLayoutParams().width = 0;
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(task.getException()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(context, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

holder.videoContainer.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("videoPublisherUserName", model.getUserName());
    intent.putExtra("thumbUrl",thumbUrl);
    intent.putExtra("videoPublisherEmail", model.getUserEmail());
    intent.putExtra("videoUrl", videoUrl);
    intent.putExtra("videoId", videoId);
    intent.putExtra("videoPublisherFullName", model.getUserFullName());
    intent.putExtra("videoPublisherId", publisherId);
    context.startActivity(intent);
});
```

But the problem is it does not behave like I want to. For example, when I click on videos it only returns the last video. Reason for that is because for loop returns only the last video's id. So I want to know what are other ways that I can get query results without using for loop.

Comment: I did not get the problem at all, what I understand is that you have this bunch of code, and you want to get a List of Video?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I just want to know is there any other way to get query results besides using for loop. I just provided code to show you how I am getting results as of now.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I think the question is pretty straight forward. I get the query result using for loop and I am asking if there is other way.

Comment: Since the result from the Task object, might contain several documents, to be able to grab them you have to iterate. What's wrong with the for loop?

Comment: @AlexMamo The problem is for example for loop returns videoId in this order => id: 1; id:2. And after that whenever I click video in recyclerview with id 1 it opens video with id 2. What I want to achieve is when I click video id 1 it opens video with id 1 and vice versa

Comment: That's not the right way to handle the onClick event. I've created a demo app. Here is the [adapter](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/adapters/MoviesAdapter.kt) class to see how to properly do that.